# Better way to store user authentication on phone app

Tags: authentication

We are creating an app and registration of user happens in following way.

1. User sends via app: email-id/phone and username.
2. Server sends a pin to enter in app via phone/email.
3. User enters the pin in the app.

After this we are thinking of two ways we could store some authentication information on app.

A. Server send a token which used by app with all subsequent requests.

OR

B. We negotiate on a secure key using Diffie–Hellman. Then there is a login function which includes server sending challenge and user answering. After this token is generated, used, and later discarded.

All communication is happening over https. Though option B looks better, option A is easier. Any particular reason we should choose B ? One reason I see is unable to 
change token, but are there any obvious security risks ?

Also comments to improve A or B are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store long lived auth-tokens, as they can be replayed.

Don't store anything connected to a global shared secret, because that could compromise the user indefinitely.

Don't store anything derived from the user password, as that opens up very easy dictionary attacks.

SHA(last-session-key) is one of the best and most secure authentication tokens you can store.  It doesn't compromise previous sessions. It's a large secret with plenty of entropy. It can only be used once. It's easy to combine with other factors if you want even more security.